# Internet Cut Outs Analasys of small network dump

Tags: networking, internet

[image]

Sometimes I experience internet cut outs, so therefore I am asking if my dump makes sence to someone who knows, give a bit of analasys to what I am looking at here. The 98.128.130.0 belongs to my ISP but my ISP does not understand why I am having 85.11.0.101 For the moment my internet is working okay, but when I started this day on the net it cut out after 1 minute. Sometimes it is almost impossible to have a stable connection. OS is Ubuntu (have 5 computers, behaves the same, all Ubuntu, have no other OS), no router and no vpn (have 3 vpn, same problem with or without vpn) 10m+1m network-cable (replaced cable no change).

Comment: It seems you are facing a rogue DHCP server, however the question is very light in details to say it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Your routing table

What you have there is simply your current routing table. I would not call that a "network dump" - *that* would usually be something created with tools like Wireshark, `tcpdump` or similar.

When a VPN is activated, all normal traffic is often routed through its encrypted tunnel - effectively, the VPN gateway/concentrator becomes the new default gateway for your system for as long as the VPN is active.

But the VPN's own encrypted traffic must still go out the "normal" gateway that was in effect before activating the VPN - otherwise the VPN software would end up in an infinite loop, re-encrypting its own encrypted traffic over and over again.

To avoid that, VPN software often adds a route that directs traffic whose destination is specifically the VPN gateway, with a 255.255.255.255 netmask. A poorly-implemented VPN client might not remove it after the VPN connection is torn down, as it does no harm when the VPN is not active.

In short, your 85.11.0.101 looks exactly like a remnant from some sort of a VPN connection... or an attempt to explicitly side-step any VPNs. Does any of your VPNs - or any software you're running - have anything to do with `riksnet.se`, or "Ratt Internet Kapacitet i Sverige AB"? That's the company that IP address belongs to, according to a simple public WHOIS lookup.

### Troubleshooting your connection

To actually analyze your internet cut-outs, more information would be needed.

First of all, it would be good to get an idea of what is the actual thing that is failing in your case: is the physical link failing? Is your ISP's gateway not responding? Or is it a case of your ISP's DNS server failing to respond?

Try running this command:

```
sudo ethtool enp2s0
```

It should ask for your password, then output the current state of your network interface. The very last line probably reads:

```
Link detected: yes
```

When your network connection cuts out, run that command again, and compare the output to the "good" state. If the outputs are identical, the physical link is apparently stable: try `sudo ethtool -S enp2s0` to view the various traffic statistics available in your network adapter. If any `_errors` or `_drops` counters increase their values whenever you have a network cutout, that suggests a bad cable connection or possibly a hardware incompatibility between the devices at the opposite ends of the network cable.

But if that looks fine, you might try running `ping 98.128.130.1` and leaving it running for an extended period. Is it getting responses consistently? Does the output change when your network cuts out? If the gateway does not respond to ping packets at all, install the `arping` tool and try it instead: it does similar testing with ARP packets, which cannot normally be disabled.

After ideally running the (ar)ping command across one network cut-out, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it and see the last few lines of statistics it prints at the end. If the packet loss is greater than 0%, something is causing network data packets to go missing between your system and the gateway. But if the packet loss **is** 0%, then either the cut is between your ISP and the rest of the world, or the problem is something else entirely.

A DNS hostname resolution failure can look a lot like a network cut-out, if you don't know how to tell them apart. Make sure you have a DNS troubleshooting command or two installed: `nslookup` or `dig` are good choices. Sometimes they are in a package that has a non-obvious name, like `bind-utils`. A modern Debian/Ubuntu should have them in package `dnsutils`.

When your network "cuts out", try either `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` or `dig www.google.com @8.8.8.8`: both these commands are querying the address of `www.google.com` *directly from Google's own public DNS server* which has the easy-to-remember IP address 8.8.8.8. If those commands return the correct response even when your network is "cutting out", then the problem might be that your ISP's resolver DNS servers suck. Unfortunately, this is not as rare as it should be. But if this turns out to be cause of your problems, the workaround is easy: just configure your systems to use some other DNS servers instead of the ones provided by your ISP.